# I am trying to restore a .sql dump database on the linux terminal and I get this notification, can someone please assist?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Restoring sql dump(https://i.stack.imgur.com/51o1k.png)

I am trying to restore a .sql dump database on the linux terminal and I get this notification, can someone please assist??

postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql -d staging_dump -U postgres -f /home/hdoop/Downloads/staging_dump.sql

Comment: It looks like you have successfully restored a dump of an empty database.

Answer (score 0):

first you must delete old database.
open psql with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

drop your database and roles.
create your database and roles.
create user with:

```
create user felan-user with encrypted password 'felan-pass';
```

then

```
grant all privileges on database your-database to your-role;
```

exit from psql with \q
and finally:

```
pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U your-db-user -d your-db your-file
```